# pip install numpy ### Warning: Using unoptimized lapack ###

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, lapack

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and python2.7.

When pip installing numpy:

```
pip install -U numpy
```

I get the warning

```
### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
```

I want to be using an optimized version of lapack - how do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that you previously installed lapack and blas libraries with

```
apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

If you have problems, you can upgrade this libraries. Try it!

Comment: I would highly recommend using OpenBLAS (`libopenblas-dev`). It supports multithreading, and is quite a lot faster than the standard CBLAS library